# json deserialize returns null value for elements c#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

here is my json response that I am trying to deserialize

```
[{
"Musician": {
    "id": "554343",
    "Name": "16408",
    "Age": "22"
},
"Albums": [{
    "id": "34343",
    "AlbumName": "Super charge",
    "ReleaseDate": "",
    "Hits": ""      
}, {
    "id": "34222",
    "AlbumName": "Super 2",
    "ReleaseDate": "",
    "Hits": ""

}]
},
{
"Musician": {
    "id": "554344",
    "Name": "16468",
    "Age": "32"
},
"Albums": [{
    "id": "34323",
    "AlbumName": "Awesome one",
    "ReleaseDate": "",
    "Hits": ""      
}, {
    "id": "34222",
    "AlbumName": "Awesome two",
    "ReleaseDate": "",
    "Hits": ""

}]
}]
```

here are my class

```
    public class Musician
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Album
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Hits { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Musician Musician { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the code i am using to deserialize objects

```
  var musicians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Musician>>(data);
  var album = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Album>>(data);
```

musicians variable shows 2 counts of record while debugging but value of elements id,Name,Age always shows null. Not able to recognize what exactly causing it.

Comment: what's in `data`?

Comment: Why are you not deserializing to a `List<RootObject>`?

Comment: That JSON string contains root objects, not raw Musician or Album arrays

Comment: i already tried deserialize RootObject problem was with the name. as I had multiple RootObjects in different class. just noticed. it works fine now @crashmstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be deserializing as collection of RootObjects.

```
var musicians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObject>>(data);
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Yes I solved this deserializing RootObject. I was referring to wrong RootObject as I am having multiple Objects into the project. Thanks for the help :)